# appendChild not working?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

Ok,so I've been reading up on JS and decided to create a quiz app to practice my new skills.So basically it's going to a fancy app that asks State Capitals one at a time,and gives the correct answer immediately.This is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>The All-Star State Capitals Quiz.</h1>
    <h3>How well do you know your state capitals?</h3>
</header>
<section id = "main">
<div id = "playArea">
    <div id = "questionArea">
    </div>
    <div id = "answerArea">
        <input  name = "choices" id = "answerA" type = "radio">
        <br>
        <input name = "choices" id = "answerB" type = "radio">
        <br>
        <input name = "choices" id = "answerC" type = "radio">
        <br>
        <input name = "choices" id = "answerD" type = "radio">
    </div>
    <!--button-->
    <div>
        <input type = "button" id = "nextQuestion" value = "Next Question">
    </div>
</div>
    <div id = "quizState">
        <p id = "result"></p>
        <p id = "correctAnswer"></p>
        <p id = "scoreSoFar"></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

So my idea was to do a separate JS MVC ish thing to update both the questionArea and answerArea dynamically.the questionarea is easy with ".innerHTML" but the answerArea is giving me a headache because I cannot get it to update the choices using appendChild(i'm using chrome on Mac).This is the js:

```
var view = 
    {
        displayQuestion:function(quiztion)
        {
            var questionArea = document.getElementById("questionArea");
            questionArea.innerHTML = quiztion;
        },
        displayAnswers: function(answers)
        {

            var answerArea = document.getElementById("answerArea");
            var inputs = document.getElementsByName("choices");
            for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
            {
                var answer = answers[i];
                var lblTxt = document.createTextNode(answer);
                var lbl = document.createElement("label").appendChild(lblTxt);
                inputs[i].appendChild(lbl);
            }
        }

    }

view.displayQuestion("1.What is the capital of Massachusetts?");
view.displayAnswers(["A.Boston","B.New Haven","C.Albany","D.Hartford"]);
```

so basically my problem is that I cannot update the choice radio buttons to the displayAnswer test example.Funny thing is I can see the choices in the DOM,without the "label" tag as I wanted.Any help?

Comment: An `<input>` can't have any children.

Comment: perhaps you wanted to set the `value`, not the `children`

Comment: He's trying to put the answer in a label after the radio button.

Comment: You should be using `insertBefore()` to insert an element at the same level of the DOM, not `appendChild()`.

Comment: Yeah,I would like a label with an answer to be inserted between the inputs whenever I call the views object.Is this now correct?  
    inputs[i].insertBefore(lbl) 
Or is my logic somehow flawed?

Comment: @BoaConstrictor - also note that the result of `lbl = document.createElement("label").appendChild(lblTxt);` is actually lblTxt - it's not the `<label>` that contains the lblTxt. Therefore, `lbl` holds a text string, and not an element that contains said text string. You should break that line up into 2 lines. The first should be `var lbl = document.createElement("label");` and the second should be `lbl.appendChild(lblTxt);`

Comment: Thanks all.I will try that @enhzflep.I have also googled some articles on the difference btn appendChild and insertBefore and will tell you how it goes :).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem with couple of fixes on your javascript code. As suggested in the comments, you can use insertBefore() but look at the definition of the method:

> The insertBefore() method inserts **a node as a child, right before an
>   existing child, which you specify**.

So in your particular case, you need to insert the new child - the label - as node child of the answer area and right before the input[i] next sibling element (next sibling because otherwise the radio will be after the label instead of before it).

```
var view = 
{
    displayQuestion:function(quiztion)
    {
        var questionArea = document.getElementById("questionArea");
        questionArea.innerHTML = quiztion;
    },
    displayAnswers: function(answers)
    {

        var answerArea = document.getElementById("answerArea");
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName("choices");
        for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
        {
            var answer = answers[i];
            var lblTxt = document.createTextNode(answer);
            var lbl = document.createElement("label").appendChild(lblTxt);
            answerArea.insertBefore(lbl, inputs[i].nextSibling);
        }
    }

}

view.displayQuestion("1.What is the capital of Massachusetts?");
view.displayAnswers(["A.Boston","B.New Haven","C.Albany","D.Hartford"]);
```

I created a fiddle for you here: **http://jsfiddle.net/5pSf5/**, so you can see the code working.

If you want go further, you could use some cloud backend service like [Teech.io](http://teech.io/), Parse or Orchestrate, to store the quizzes in the cloud and get them via API without the need to set up a database. Plus, Teech.io has some specific features for this kind of apps, like autocorrection of quizzes.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the founder of Teech.io :)